# Oracle Forms Default Button When Enter is Pressed

Tags: oracleforms

How do I specify which button on the form is the default button which will be pressed when someone presses `Enter` from anywhere on the screen?

Comment: This seems like a very basic thing, but my developer is saying we need to adjust a server key configuration, which seems pretty radical for such a simple problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in oracle forms with normal functionality.

The only thing you can do if you really want to accomplish this is to re-map your enter key see the following [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14032/configure011.htm) on how to do this.

Then you can map your enter key to a key-trigger and in that key-trigger you can put the code you want to execute when the enter-key is pressed.

The only downside to this is that in every application the enter key is pressed the same key-trigger will be triggered if it exists in your application. So you can't use this method to only use the enter key in 1 form and normal use (go to the next field) in the other applications. Then you have to make in every application that key-trigger with the code `next_item;`